# Page Not Found error after adding SSL to my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I have created a website in WordPress. For my website I have added SSL certificate. Before adding SSL it is working fine. But after adding SSL my pages are showing:

```
Not Found

The requested URL ...  was not found on this server.
```

Without https (I mean http) pages are working fine but with https I am getting error.

I have installed a plugin wordpress-https also.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem is coming from a very simple place:

Most web-servers today use a control panel and than it manges the traffic of the site (databases, requests and more).

Now, with every domain registerd in your user at the CP you have `public_html` folder and a `private_html` folder.

The `public_html` folder is the regular (default) folder you use and it points to **http://**
The `private_html` folder is the secure connection folder which is what you are looking for, and it is pointing to **https://**

So all you need to do is reinstall the wordpress in the `private_html` folder which is the pointer of **https://**

This should work for you :)

Comment: zpanel cp. can i create private_html in that cp.?

Comment: well at first you need to install the ssl to the panel:
http://docs.zpanelcp.com/?node=21